# Click listener for drawable inside custome framelaout class android

Tags: android, drawable, android-canvas, android-framelayout

hi I am developing android application in which i am using one custom frame layout class. Inside that class I am using one drawable and with the help of canvas i m drawing that. I did this in following way :

```
public class BackgroundContainer extends FrameLayout implements OnTouchListener{

    Drawable mShadowedBackground;

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
    }

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
    }

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
    }

    private void init() {
    mShadowedBackground =
            getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar);

    }

    @Override  
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
    {  
        Log.i("OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO", "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
       switch(event.getAction())  
       {  

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {  

            invalidate();  
        }  
       }  
       return true;  
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        mShadowedBackground.setBounds(getWidth()-150, 0, getWidth(), mOpenAreaHeight);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, mOpenAreaTop);
        mShadowedBackground.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
    }

}
```

Now I am want to listen click even on my drawable. I implement ontouch event but its not working. Am i doing it in wrong way. Need help thank you.

Comment: Why dint you use a clickListener instead of touch. You want clicks right ?

Comment: yeah i just want to detect click on my drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Drawables are not clickable as it is not considered as a view.

Comment: Thank you deepak but i am not getting your answer. Can you please explain more.

Comment: when you override the method onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event),  you only tell that all the view which will be touched will do whatever is in that method. But to know that which view should be using the touchevent() method, you need to add a listener to that view. In your case, it will be something like this       drawable.setOnTouchListener(context); Also you may have to store the context which you get in the constructor as global variable so that you can use it inside the draw() method. Please Accept the answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: I tried this but it gives error `The method setOnTouchListener(Context) is undefined for the type Drawable`

Comment: I tried in this way `mShadowedBackground.setOnTouchListener(Context)`. Am i doing something wrong need help thank you

Comment: Oh. Sorry for that. As you may be knowing the click and touch listeners can only be added to a view, like layouts, widgets, etc. It cannot be used on a drawable. You can try setting this drawable as resource to an imageview and set touchlistener to that.

Answer (score 0):

Like deepak already said: by implementing the corresponding listener you just provide the behavior what should happen for a specific event. You still need to add the listener :) In your case this would help (in your init()):

```
setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank you aandd for replay I tried this but it gives me error `The method setOnTouchListener(Context) is undefined for the type Drawable`

Comment: Drawable is not a widget which is capable of receiving this event. Look at my example :) Just add the listener to your FrameLayout - so just write "setOnTouchListener(this);" which calls the method on your extended instance of FrameLayout.

Comment: I tried this sir but it still not working i define it in like this way  `setOnClickListener(abc);` and `public OnClickListener abc = new OnClickListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Log.i("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT", "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
  }
 };`  but still not working any other way to do this

Comment: Hm... it should work in my opinion from what you have posted. Can you please post your complete code with the changes made?

And just to be sure: You put the log-level to information in your logcat and have no applied filters (log-tag...)? Maybe the log entry is just not displayed if it's set to debug or error...